# Removed from Google after 404 errors

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, google-ranking

I had a problem with my host, so all my pages returned 404 and therefor this pages was removed from Google. The problem is that my pages ranked very well on Google.

I have fixed the problem now - but does my page get the same rank again, is there something I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Google crawled my website again, I have the same ranking again.